# Call an Array in a JavaScript file from Java when info can be see in debug mode

Tags: javascript, java, object

In the `alert();` I want to call the issueId display in the debug mode but I can't manage to do it.

If I put `alert(data);` I have this : `

> [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

`

But when i write this `alert(data.issueId);` it doesn't recognize the issueId.

Really need help please.

[image: Screenshot of my code and debug mode]

Comment: Because `data` is an _array_ of objects

Comment: Yes but is it possible to call issueId from the array ?

Answer (score -1):

use for or while loop to access data 
example

```
for(var i =0;i<data.length;i++)
{
alert(data[i]);
}
```

Comment: it's already in a loop (not shown on the screen) but as I say this don't work. I have 12 time [objet Object]